# SQL Server Merge Replication error

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am getting a very strange error message at one of our client sites and I am having very little luck trying to figure out what is going on.

> Hr=80040154 ERR:OpenDB failed getting
>   pub version 28627

That is the error message that is from the Merge Agent (IIS) logs.  From what I can tell, it is a COM error not being able to load a specific COM object, but I don't know which one.  From that, I think this client might not have something installed, but I don't know what that something.

Does any one have any thoughts about what might not be installed?  Any other ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a DLL that wasn't registered.  It was sqloledb.dll (C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB).  I found this by using the ?diag on the merge agent.

http:////sqlcesa35.dll?diag

That page shows a nice summary of the versions of DLLs that it is using and such.  When I did that at the client's site, it showed "unknown" for the version of that DLL.  Running `regsvr32` on the DLL allowed sqlcesa35.dll to see it and the diag page showed a version number.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be related to permissions: Did you configure a snapshot share and give the IUSER_Machine name rights to Read and List Files and Folders?

You could restart the synchronization with verbose history logging as described here: [How to enable replication agents for logging to output files in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312292).

Check these:

- Ensure your subscription database is not timing out on auto-grow.
- Make sure there is enough space to apply the snapshot on the subscriber

Comment: As a troubleshooting step we have Everyone with full permissions to that snapshot share (both NTFS and file share permissions).
We can give the logging thing a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.

From what I can tell, nothing is ever getting to SQL Server.  It seems to me like the merge agent can't talk to SQL Server at all. I should have said this before, but just to be clear, the merge agent and SQL Server are both running on the same machine.

Comment: That logging did not help. Is there any way to look at the sqlcesa35.dll and see which COM objects it is trying to use?